# Profiling advice - trying to pinpoint site loading issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, profiling

I've taken over a wordpress e-comm (although this question is more about profiling generally) site which has a performance issue which seemingly only affects one specific area in the admin section of the CMS. When trying to edit one particular type of product, which has a large number of attributes attached to it, the page effectively causes the browser to crash 99% of the time. I expected this to be down to MySQL queries causing the bottleneck, however when I profiled the db, I got the following results:

Total Queries: 174 - Total Time Of MySQL Queries: 0.11370

This suggests the bottleneck is happening elsewhere, but I'm not sure where it could be. If I run YSlow on the page, there is nothing drastic there which would explain the issue, although there are around 20 scripts and stylesheets loaded, so some optimisation could be done there. I'm going to enable an opcode cache library which will improve PHP performance, but is there anything else I can do to try to identify the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: If the browser crashes there is probably too much HTML in a specific way that crashes the browser. Or was "crashing the browser" not really crashing the browser?

Comment: Well, in Chrome, the page freezes for a few minutes, sometimes recovers, sometimes does not.

Comment: Was the page already loaded fully? Did you disable javascripts?

Comment: I have tested with and without JS enabled. Without JS, page seems to load more consistently, although it still takes a very long time

Comment: Metric as well the output size of the page. I suspect it's quite large. Disable javascript for the moment to reduce side-effects.

Comment: Also you should track the I/O of your server when you request that page.

Comment: hi @hakre - sorry i'm only just getting back to this now. Ok, the total output size of the page is 5.1MB. The content is already gzipped. I'll check the server and report back

Comment: If you have 5.1 MB of gzipped HTML, it actually is much larger. Even browsers have improved over time, I would consider such a HTML chunk very large (too large) and I won't expect any browser to deal fast with it. Sounds like a design problem. Reduce the amount of HTML that needs to be passed to the browser by allowing more differentiated access to the values that need editing (e.g. with paging, ajax etc.).

Comment: Thanks @hakre - yeah, i might have to modify the plugin then to reduce the amount of html being loaded. I'm sure the opcode cache will help too

Comment: Server side won't help when you spam the browser with large HTML. As wordpress is using jquery with it's selector syntax there is a lot that it needs to do (next to the browser which needs to deal with the HTML, too).

Answer (score 1):

[firebug](http://getfirebug.com/downloads) (add-on to firefox) is the best tool that I know to locate such issues. You can also install another pluging called "[page speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/)". it will show you exactly which part takes longer to load.
another option is to debug your code with "time" printing and see which has the biggest time-gap:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Answer (score 1):

Use a Profiler like Xdebug...if the problem is not their in database my be PHP has the problem..find out which part of code is taking longer...Xdebug will tell you time taken per function call as well as memory usase.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I profiled wordpress, it took me a dozen `microtime(1)`-based calculations to spot the place that took half of 2.5 seconds loading time. It was loading and parsing of .mo localization file.

Also considerable gain was from installing APC cache, as it turned out that wordpress is a heavy bloated monster consumes a lot of time to parse it's codes.

Answer (score 1):

I would

- Use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)'s or Chrome's Net panel to see if it's the page or the JavaScript/CSS/imges that are causing the slowdown (front-end)
- Use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to see how long the page takes: `time curl -b PHPSESSID=123 http://example.com/wp-admin/`
- Enable/install [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) and turn profiling on. Use [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) to see which functions are causing the biggest delays.